# In CSS Grid, why do explicit rows not render if the overall space exceeds 100% of the parent?

Tags: css, css-grid

Using CSS Grid, I am trying to create a grid that (sometimes) takes more than `100%` of the containing element's height. How can this be achieved?

When creating 3 rows that together take `100%`, the explicit grid is shown just fine:

[image]

https://codepen.io/tommedema/pen/dKqwrZ?editors=1100#0

However, if prior rows take more than 100%, the third row is suddenly gone, even though it is explicitly defined:

[image]

https://codepen.io/tommedema/pen/jKvdOO?editors=1100#0

Note that there is no scrollbar going 40% (140 - 100) further down, which I would have expected there to be.

**Updated question**

When explicitly defining `grid-row` from the first to last row to at least one child, the overflow (and scrollbar) does show. This is surprising, as I would expect it to overflow without such statement too:

New CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 100% 20%;
}

/* 
  allows for row overflow to not be cropped
  see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048661
*/
body::after {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/tommedema/pen/MXqRPW?editors=1100#0

Even more surprising, when you put a grid inside this grid with the same setup, the `::after` trick does not work for this inner grid.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you've limited the height of the container to a fixed 100%. The overflow is clipped.

In addition, percentage heights don't work as expected with grid rows (see note below).

For a simpler and stronger solution use `vh` units.

```
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 100vh 20vh;
}
```

[**revised codepen 1**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKOGNg?editors=1100#0)

From the [CSS Grid specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing), with regard to `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`:

> If the size of the grid container depends on the size of its tracks,
>   then `<percentage>` must be treated as `auto`.

So if you release the fixed height and use, let's say, `min-height: 100%` on the container, then your `20% 100% 20%` determine the height of the container, compute to `auto` as a result and, per the [`auto` algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-stretch), resolve to three equal height rows.

[**revised codepen 2**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKOBvQ?editors=1100#0)

Comment: Unfortunately I am actually trying to move away from `vh`, which is not obvious from my question -- sorry about that. Reason is that `vh` causes my components to not be re-useable. To make them re-useable, I need to define row height based on the parent's height. Only percentage units would achieve this. Therefore the question really is how I can prevent the overflow from being clipped? Using `min-height` does not seem to work.

Comment: Understood. As you noted (and I hinted in my answer), the grid rows are not respecting the true percentage values. They are shrinking to equal size. There is no `flex-shrink: 0` in grid, so the only alternative I can think of right now is using other units of length.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but why is it that if I add "spacer divs" with the HTML and CSS as in my updated question, the overflow does show?

Comment: You're too fast -- try again. ;)

Comment: It's not the empty divs that are making it work. It's the `grid-row` rules you've defined on each element. If you remove those rules, the layout falls back to your original problem, even with the spacer divs present. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXqRvM?editors=1100

Comment: I see, but there is no way to define `grid-row` rules without having elements to set these at. Do you have an explanation on why these `grid-row` rules result in the behavior that I had expected in the original situation?

Comment: basically it works with this hack: `body::after { content: ""; grid-row: 1 / -1; }` https://codepen.io/tommedema/pen/MXqRPW?editors=1100#0